# Preventing people from spamming image upload form

Tags: php, html, css, image, upload

im working an Image host service and one of the problems with that is how will i prevent from people refreshing the form and forcing the form to re-upload the image over and over until i run out of disk space (im limited to 20GB). 
Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way of doing this is using sessions. When the user uploads a file, you can increment the total upload usage by the size of the last uploaded image. Before uploading a new file you can check to see that the session hasn't exceeded the maximum (I'm assuming you want to use 20GB). You can also clear the limit after a certain about of time as well. Here's a little example to put you in the right direction.

```
session_start();

// 20 GB
$rateLimit = 20 * 1073741824;

// 5 minutes (in seconds)
$rateDuration = 5 * 60;

// check to see if we've exceeded the upload threshold for the current window
if(isset($_SESSION['uploadUsage']) && $_SESSION['uploadUsage'] > $rateLimit) {
    die('You\'ve exceed the maximum upload size rate limit!');
}

// check if we can reset our limit window
if(time() - $_SESSION['lastRateWindow'] >= $rateDuration) {
    $_SESSION['uploadUsage'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['lastRateWindow'] = time();
}

// add this file size to the total in this rate window, 
// assuming the uploaded file is named "myFile"
$_SESSION['uploadUsage'] += $_FILES['myFile']['size'];

// handle your actual file uploads
handleFileUploads();
```

Comment: No, the limit for my account is 20GB, not per user

Comment: Got it. You can change the limit to something more respectable then, such as 50 MB (`$rateLimit = 50 * 1048576;`).

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst, the problem with this approach is that user can still upload infinitely number of file without restriction because user can delete their SESSION ID from their cookie and the system will treat them as new user.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few but it does not totally prevent, just annoy them (or you can also say it can annoy honest user as well).

- Limit number of uploads or size that user can upload per IP for limited time.
- Limit size of all user upload per day.
- Use reliable CAPTCHA.

You can also clear out unused images. For example: user uploaded image will be deleted if it hasn't been used by user for 30 days.

Comment: What CAPTCHA do you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

Also give CSRF technique a try. `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery`